# Fetching excel data on local file into a html website without using ActiveX

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel, activexobject

We're a group of guys working on a bachelor project for a consultant firm that wants an easy step by step webpage/program for analysing numbers for consultant purposes. We want to make this cross-browser compatible, but looking across the internet it seems like the only way it will work is with IE and its "safe" ActiveX function. 
Most of the answers we've found involves, as far as I know, real time updates/refreshing of the excel spreadsheet, therefore the need for ActiveX? This is not exactly what we are looking for.

The excel spreadsheet we are looking to import looks the same every time, but with different data on it and will be fetched by the page manually when needed, which is why we just want a simple browse file button on the page, fetching the spreadsheet and neatly positioning the numbers required into fields on the page.

Is there no way to do this with JavaScript or PHP without using:

ActiveXObject ?

**Edited : 30'th of October.**

We've looked into the PHPExcel library, started working on it, but getting this error when just trying to locate the file we want to read.

*Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Reader_C:/SKOLE/test/Excelrapporter/Balanse.xls' not found in C:\Programmer\XAMPP\htdocs\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php on line 170*

Here is the current code for just trying to read the file:

```html
<?php
$data = "";
/*require_once("bachelor/classes/phpexcel/IOFactory.php");*/
require_once 'C:/Programmer/XAMPP/htdocs/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$filename = 'C:/SKOLE/test/Excelrapporter/Balanse.xls';
try{
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($filename);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
}catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

When going through tutorials on this online, we were told to put PHPExcel into the Xampp/htdoc directory, which we have done. This is why we have included 2 seperate complete paths to both the IOFactory.php and the excel file we want to read.

Any help on what we are doing wrong would be greatly apprechiated.

Comment: No don't need to touch ActiveX if you're doing it with PHP, because it's running serverside, not in the browser..... you just need to upload the file and parse it using a library like PHPExcel and then render it as HTML markup for web page display on any browser.... about 5 lines of code to parse and render

Comment: you could check out some javascript libraries.. such as [xlsx.js](https://github.com/stephen-hardy/xlsx.js) and use them.. of course the files can't be "local" as in client side. But maybe you could make the user upload it?

Comment: Will I be able to fetch the necessary numbers from the spesific excel cells and into the webpage fields by just using libraries, parsing and rendering it as a HTML markup for web page display , or will it display the exact entire excel worksheet on the page ?

Comment: Libraries tend to offer a number of different ways of working: it's up to you exactly what you want to do. PHPExcel provides an HTML Writer that can render the entire workbook as HTML markup, but you can also render individual worksheets. Alternatively, it provides methods to retrieve the raw data from the workbook, allowing you to process or render it however you want from within a PHP script. Why not take a look and see, then

Comment: I will have a look. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Nvm, managed to figure it out.
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($filename);
needed to be:
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($InputFileType);